# How to convert the dictionary containing keys and list of list value?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, nested-lists

- How to convert the dictionary containing keys and list of list values to dictionary containing keys and list, drop duplicated in the newly created list ?
- I tried running the following function and the computer got an 'memory error'

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)    
for k, v in zip(df_Group.guest_group, df_Group.list_guest):
  for item in v:
    v.append(item)    
  my_dict[k].append(set(v))
```

- My origin dictionary created from 2 columns of one dataframe like: `{Group1: [[1,2,3,4], [1, 2, 5, 6 ]]}`
- I want my dictionary like : `{Group1: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, what you essentially want to do is flatten your list while keeping unique items.
The unique items can be achieved by converting the `list` into `set` and then back to `list`.
The unpacking part is really well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists?) post. Here's a working code for you -

```
df_dict = {
    'Group1': [[1,2,3,4], [1, 2, 5, 6 ]],
    'Group2': [[1,2], [2,3],[2,3,4]]
}

final_dict = {}

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    # flatten the list using double list comprehension
    flat_list = [item for sublist in v for item in sublist]
    final_dict[k] = list(set(flat_list))
```

This gives the `final_dict` as -

```
{'Group1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'Group2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Please tell me if this answers your query.

Edit for Integer values in between the lists -
If we have a list with integer values in between, then you will get the `int object not iterable error`, to solve it we can check the instance to be `int` and make the item list by ourselves

Working code -

```
df_dict = {
    'Group1': [[1,2,3,4], 3, [1, 2, 5, 6 ]],
    'Group2': [[1,2], [2,3],[2,3,4]],
}

final_dict = {}

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    # making a new list 
    new_list = []
    for item in v:
        # for int we will convert it to 1 length list
        if isinstance(item, int):
            item = [item]
        for ele in item:
            new_list.append(ele)
    final_dict[k] = list(set(new_list))

final_dict
```

Final dict -

```
{'Group1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'Group2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

As expected

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried this way, but got error  'int' object is not iterable' and cant solve with range(len(v))

Comment: If you used the dictionary that I have given in the code, then you shouldn't get that error. Can I know what type of dictionary are you using?

Comment: I have added an edit for your problem, tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: My dictionary type is 'defaultdict' with value type is 'defaultdict object of collections module'. When I print dict,  its like:  'defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Group1': [[170323, 38785, 43158, ...], [170323, 38785, 43158...]], 'Group2':[[42276, 67349, 56879,...], [422763, 673490, 588879,...],...]]})

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but still get error ' 'int' object is not iterable'. This dictionary contains all keys and values of 2 columns in a dataframe, which keys is 'group_name' and values is 'list of guest_id'.

Comment: If I use this way, dictionary will not contain all NON-duplicated values. Each group (keys) only contains a certain amount of equal value is 11 list_guest_id) !

Comment: I am not sure I understand you well,    "not contain all NON-duplicated values" do you mean It doesn't have the values that appear in more than one list (in a single group)? then I think you are mistaken.  In the above example, 4 is a NON-duplicated value and it appears in the final answer.

Comment: I dont know...it seems like the list_guest_id that are not duplicated with previous ids will be replaced when they have same 1 group_name (keys) and same length list_id_guest (11 id).

Comment: Can you provide me the data too? Without it whatever I answer you it would seem vague or won't work to you.

Comment: When i create dictionary with dict type 'defaultdict' for 2 columns . My dictionary have total 284 group_name, with each group containing 19 to 152 list_id and the same length list of 11 ids. For each row in dataframe, each group_name will change the list of ids in it, but the list length remains the same.